# Not able to validate all nested child elements length

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 1 object which contains nested child like below:

```
$scope.artists.materials.items[]
```

Now i would have several artist which will contains list of items but in this i want to check total length of each item of artists and if mismatch found then i want to return true or false.

> Problem is when i dont have items for any of the artist then still
>   i am getting false

Idea here is to store the length of the items from the first artist and make sure all of them have that same items length.

**Code:**

```
function checkItemsValidity() {
      for (var i = 1; i < $scope.artists.length; index++) {
            if ($scope.artists[i].materials.items != undefined && $scope.artists[0].materials.items) {
                if($scope.artists[i].materials.items.length != $scope.artists[0].materials.items[0].length) {
                             return false;
                }
            }        
                             return false;
        }
            return true;
    }
```

**Case 1**:In case of only 1 artist then return true becuase no other artist to compare

**Case 2**: In case of 2 artist with 2 items for both artist return true else false;

**Case 3**: In case of 3 artist with 2 items for artist1 and artist 2 and 5 items for artist3 then return false;

Can anybody please hlep me with this??

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to see if every artist just has the same number of items in their materials object?

Comment: @dominic aquilina Yes thats right. Every artist should have same number of items.if no artist have items then function should return true or if  all artist have same number of items then also function should return true else false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all artists need to have the same number of materials...

```
function checkMaterials (arists)
{
  if (!artists || !artists.length) { return false; }
  if (artists.length < 2)          { return true; }

  var valid = true;
  var materialCount

  try
  {
    //All artists must have the same number of materials, so we
    //can test against the number of materials that the first
    //artist has and reduce the number times we access the object
    materialCount = (artists[0].materials.items || []).length;
  }
  catch (exception)
  {
    //Object is malformed
    return false;
  }

  //Loop through the remaining artists and check how
  //many materials they have against the first artist
  for (var i = 1; i < artists.length; i++)
  {
    if (!artists[i].materials || ((artists[i].materials.items || []).length !== materialCount)
    {
      //Once one failed case is found, we can stop checking
      valid = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  return valid;
}

//Test data
var validArtists = [{
  materials: {
    items: [1, 2, 3]
  }
}, {
  materials: {
    items: [1, 3, 4]
  }
}];

var invalidArtists = [{
  materials: {
    items: [1, 2]
  }
}, {
  materials: {
    items: [3]
  }
}];

//Tests
console.log (checkMaterials (validArsists)); //Prints true
console.log (checkMaterials (invalidArtists)); //Prints false
```

Comment: Why do we have for loop outside of try block and apart from that why are you checking length on artist instead of items??

Comment: The try block is to defend against malformed data on the first element. After that it's a comparison with its own guards, but adding those same guards on the first element would be less efficient. And the length on artist is just an additional safeguard on the input. If there's nothing to test, the test fails. If there's only one artist, the test succeeds immediately because it's trivial.

Comment: Your solution worked.Thank you so much for sparing your precious time from busy schedule and helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

As I understand you just want to check if every artist has the same number of items. This code:

```
var result, materialsNumber;
for (var artist of $scope.artists) {
   var artistMaterialsNumber = artist.materials.items.length;
   if (!materialsNumber) {
       materialsNumber = artistMaterialsNumber;
   }
   result = (materialsNumber === artistMaterialsNumber);
   if (!result) {
      break;
   }
}

return result;
```

should be useful for that. It remembers number of items of first artist and checks if every other artist has same number of items. In case there is artist with different item number code breaks and returns `false`.

Comment: Thank you so much for sparing your precious time from busy schedule and helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can try this also...

```
var vFirstItemLength = artists[0].materials.items.length;
result = (artists.filter(function(item){return item.materials.items.length===vFirstItemLength;}).length === (artists.length));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sparing your precious time from busy schedule and helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var artists = [{
 materials: {
  items: [1, 2, 3]
 }
}, {
 materials: {
  items: [1, 3]
 }
}, {
 materials: {
  items: [1, 2, 3]
 }
}, {
 materials: {}
}];

artists.some(function(artist, i) {
 if (i === 0) return false;
 if (artists.length === 1) {
  console.log("Index " + i);
  console.log(true);
  return true; // length is one
 }
 if (artists[0].materials.items) {
  if (!artist.materials.items) {
   console.log("Index " + i);
   console.log(false);
   return false; // items doesn't exist. Return true/false, whatever works for you
  } else if (artist.materials.items &&
   artist.materials.items.length === artists[0].materials.items.length) {
   console.log("Index " + i);
   console.log(true);
   return true; // length is equal
  } else {
   console.log("Index " + i);
   console.log(false);
   return false; // length is unequal
  }
 } else {
  if (artist.materials.items) {
   console.log("Index " + i);
   console.log(false);
   return false; // one has  items, other doesn't
  } else {
   console.log("Index " + i);
   console.log(true);
   return true; // both have no items
  }

 }
});
```

Why don't you try

```
artists.some(function(artist, i) {
    if (i === 0) return false;
    if (artists.length === 1) {
        console.log("Index " + i);
        console.log(true);
        return true; // length is one
    }
    if (artists[0].materials.items) {
        if (!artist.materials.items) {
            console.log("Index " + i);
            console.log(false);
            return false; // items doesn't exist. Return true/false, whatever works for you
        } else if (artist.materials.items &&
            artist.materials.items.length === artists[0].materials.items.length) {
            console.log("Index " + i);
            console.log(true);
            return true; // length is equal
        } else {
            console.log("Index " + i);
            console.log(false);
            return false; // length is unequal
        }
    } else {
        if (artist.materials.items) {
            console.log("Index " + i);
            console.log(false);
            return false; // one has  items, other doesn't
        } else {
            console.log("Index " + i);
            console.log(true);
            return true; // both have no items
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: This is simply not working as because when i dont have items for any materials in that case i am getting error:$scope.artists[i].materials.items is undefined

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I just want to validate items on both the sides of artist.If for any artist items are mismatching then only i want to return false.With your function if items of 1st artist and 2nd artist are matching but 3rd artist items is not matching then i will get true.I would like to return true at the end while making all sorts of comparision among all artist items

Comment: See i have updated my question to include case and please dont use angular js forEach loop as return keyword doesnot works with this for loop and so break keyword too

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer again. You can just replace the `forEach` with Angular's `forEach` loop. It should be identical, except for the order of index and item are opposite

Comment: return and break doenst works with angular for loop too that is why i have used javscript native for loop

Comment: I have used native javascript as well. `array.forEach` is a native Js function

Comment: The native array.forEach can't be ended early, though. Calling return in the callback function (regardless of what you return) simply ends that iteration and moves to the next one.

Comment: @Learning I've updated the answer further to handle the case that @ dominic Aquilina has mentioned. Is something missing in the answer? Does this work for you?

Comment: Thank you so much for sparing your precious time from busy schedule and helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 1):

Should solve the issue:

```
function checkValidity() {
    var itemsCounts = $scope.artists.map(function(artist) { return artist.materials.items.length; });
    return itemsCounts.length > 1
        ? itemsCounts.every(function(count) { return count === itemsCounts[0]; })
        : true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sparing your precious time from busy schedule and helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do as follows;

```js
var artists = [{ materials: { items: [1, 2, 3] } },
               { materials: { items: [1, 2] } },
               { materials: { items: [] } },
               { materials: { items: [1] } },
               { materials: { items: [1, 2, 3] } }
              ];
     result = artists.map(artist => artist.materials.items.length)
                     .every(length => length === artists[0].materials.items.length);
console.log(result);
```

```js
var artists = [{ materials: { items: [1, 2, 3] } }
              ];
     result = artists.map(artist => artist.materials.items.length)
                     .every(length => length === artists[0].materials.items.length);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sparing your precious time from busy schedule and helping me and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
function checkItemsValidity() {
  if ($scope.artists.length === 1) {
      return true;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.artists.length; i++) {
    //this condition might be unnecessary, I assumed items can be undefined from your code.
    if (typeof $scope.artists[i].materials.items === 'undefined') {
        $scope.artists[i].materials.items = [];
    }
    if (i === 0) {
        continue;
    }
    if ($scope.artists[i].materials.items.length !== $scope.artists[0].materials.items.length) {
        return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

And a fiddle with some tests: https://jsfiddle.net/6x7zpkxe/1/

Comment: Thank you so much for sparing your precious time from busy schedule and helping me and please keep helping like this :)